# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm getting this error when i want to start my asp.net web app

```
The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047) 
...

Line 22:     {
Line 23:         public ApplicationDbContext()
Line 24:             : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
Line 25:         {
Line 26:         }
```

Its MVC web app connected to oracle database and I used EntinyFramework 6.1.3  over NuGet,

I'm using windows 7 64-bit,
V.Studio 2015
and 32-bit ODAC 12c Release 4

I tried to set in Visual studio to start in x64 or x86, doesn't help..

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Code behind:
Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.12.1.0.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20160811110342.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20160811110342;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX"
      providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
    <add name="xpf.printing" connectionString="xpoprovider=MSSqlServer;data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ReportService.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=120" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ....
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=4.12.1.0.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  ....
</configuration>
```

IdentityModels.cs :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should down load from the Oracle site the 32Bite Oracle.DataClient and set the project to be x86 there is a known issue / bug with the 64bit client version and it will work on a 64 bit OS using the 32bit `Oracle.DataAccess.Client;` I work with this on a daily basis and I copy the dll into a dependency folder setting the CopyLocal =true property when I add the reference

Comment: how are you adding these references?  nuget?

Comment: I posted more info bout my problem..
@MethodMan : im usin 32Bite Oracle.DataClient ... Didn't understand u about dll, from where to where to copy and what reference?? Thank you.

Comment: if you are not familiar about how to add a reference as well as setting the properties of the individual reference, then you will not be able to solve your problem.. sorry..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same bug and I has been fixed like this:
You need change your web.config like this:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework"></defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

And you need to install entityFramework
1. Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.1
2. Add reference from your link setup ODAC 12c Release 4
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll to your project.
It's will done